# Image hover jquery effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Hy there.
What I'm trying is this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.wrapper').hover(function() {
$('.image', this).animate({width:"110%",opacity:"0.5"}{duration:100,queue:false});
$('h4',this).animate({ margin-left: "10px"} {duration:300,queue:false});
$('p',this).animate({ margin-left: "40px", display: "block"} {duration:200,queue:false});
}); 
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ygqouhk1/

But the problem is it doesn't work and when it works sometimes it applies the animations to all divs with the same class and it doesn't go back to normal state after mouse leave. I'm not so good with jquery but I would like to make something like this css effect just in jquery. It must not be exactly like this one, just similar I will try to tweak the positions and colors later on:

http://jsfiddle.net/shomz/J28Yp/19/

```
#container .photo {
    transition: .3s all linear;
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    left:-5%;
    top:-20px;
    position: relative;
    background:url('http://tympanus.net/Development/HoverEffectIdeas/img/11.jpg') no-repeat center center;

}

#container:hover .photo {
    transform: matrix(0.95, 0, 0, 0.95, 0, 0);
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#container:hover .desc {    
    margin: -20px 0 0 10px;
    opacity: 1;
}

.desc {
    transition: .3s all linear;
    font-size: 14px;
    top: 60px;
    width: 210px;
    text-align: right;
    left: 20px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    border-right: 1px solid;
    opacity:0;
    margin: 0;
}

.title {
    font-size:30px;
    bottom: 20px;
    right: 40px;
}

.desc,
.title {
    position: absolute;  
    z-index:2;
    color: #ffffff;
    font-family: Arial;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: what do you mean "it doesn't work?"  What is the incorrect behavior?What should the correct behavior be?

Comment: also, please provide your HTML too.

Comment: The hover doesn't trigger the animation. It should make the image a bit wider add some margins to left for the p and h4 and on mouseleave back to normal state w/o the margin and width without affecting same classes, .wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.image').hover(
            function() {
                $(".rollOver", this).fadeIn();
            },
            function() {
                $(".rollOver", this).fadeOut();
            }
        );
```

You need this code. Check full demo here "http://jsfiddle.net/SaurabhGhewari/oLrpL3wy/3/"

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.wrapper').hover(function(e) {
    $(e.target).animate({width:"110%",opacity:"0.5"}{duration:100,queue:false});
});
```

$(e.target) represents clicked element so animation doesn't applies to all elements with same class.