# How to apply nested css using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have stylesheet.css file which contain the following:

```
.vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover {
    background-image: url(../images/sticcky_nav_hover.png)
}
.vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.navfirst:hover {
    background-position: 28px -2px;
}
.vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.navsecond:hover {
    background-position: 24px -82px;
}
```

How to apply this hover css on click of the `<a href...>` element and hover effect should remain after the click event ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image hover jquery effect](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25204216/image-hover-jquery-effect)

Comment: A pure CSS option could be to use `:focus` pseudo-class as well, but using JavaScript you should add/remove classes containing the proper styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll show you have you can achieve this for the first `a` tag. You can replicate the same for the remaining.

Change the CSS to assign those properties to another class as well, eg. `selected`

```
.vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
.vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a.selected {
    background-image: url(../images/sticcky_nav_hover.png);
}
```

Then add the following jQuery code to toggle the class on click event.

```
$('.vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a').click(function() {
    $(this).toggleClass('selected');    
});
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I want that this hover effect should remain after click that means if i click then it should remain as it is hover

Comment: That is exactly what happens in this case.

Comment: can i replicate all three css style

Comment: Yes you can. You will have to use a different class name other than selected for the other classes (ie. .navfirst, and .navsecond)

Comment: hello karanmhatre, i cant replicate this css in stylesheet can i replicate it using jQuery and if yes then how ?,Thanks

Comment: You can add the necessary properties in jQuery itself using the 'css' attribute. http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 0):

I think that's your solution (touch devices should work too)

```
      .vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:hover, 
      .vertical-navigation .navbar-default .navbar-nav > li > a:active {background-image: url(../images/sticcky_nav_hover.png)
```